# Alternative of find in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a simple problem . I want to replace all values  in a vector which are greater than a limit with constant. I don't want to use loop or find option.

```
AA=rand(10,4)
AA(AA(:,4)>0.5)=1;  % want to replace all values in 4th column % NOT WORKING
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a subscript for the 4<sup>th</sup> column in the assignment:

```
AA(AA(:,4)>0.5, 4) = 1;
```